# Apriori estimate for a specify quasilinear eiilptic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, parabolic-pde

I got some problem when proving a priori estimate for the solution. For $\lambda>0$ big enough and $\kappa>0$ very small, consider the following elliptic equation:
$$
\lambda u-\Delta u(x)=f(x)+\kappa|\nabla u(x)|^2,
$$
where $f\in L^p(R^n)$ with $p>n/2$. To solve the above equation, we only need to show a priori estimate, that is, one can assume that there exists a $u\in W^{2,p}$ satisfies the above eqaution, and we need to show that
$$
\|u\|_{2,p}\leq C\|f\|_p\,\,(or,\,\, C\|f\|_p^2)
$$
For this, we have
$$
\|u\|_{2,p}\leq C\|f+\kappa|\nabla u|^2\|_p\leq C\|f\|_p+C\kappa\||\nabla u|^2\|_p.
$$
Since $u\in W^{2,p}$ and $p>n/2$, by Sobolev embedding theorem, we have $\nabla u\in W^{1,p}\hookrightarrow L^q(R^n)$ with $q>2p$. Thus, $|\nabla u|^2\in L^p(R^n)$.

But the question is: we could only have
$$
\|u\|_{2,p}\leq C\|f\|_p+C\kappa\|\nabla u\|_{2p}^2\leq C\|f\|_p+C\kappa\|u\|_{2,p}^2.
$$
Is there any possible to handel this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: I want to solve the above equation by showing some priori estimates. I specify the problem more clear.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you should use an interpolation estimate for $\|\nabla u\|_{2p}$ and then Cauchy's inequality with $\epsilon$ and absorb $\|u\|_{2,p}$ back into left hand side. Then it reduces to estimating $\|u\|_p$.

Comment: Yes. The point is that, the norm $\|u\|_{2,p}$ can not be absored by the left hand using Cauchy inequality. Because the right hand side is $\|u\|_{2,p}^2$.

Comment: Use the version of Cauchy with $p$ and $q$ exponents, sometimes called Young's inequality.

Comment: Young's inequality can only make the power of $\|u\|_{2,p}$ even bigger. The term $\|u\|_{2,p}^2$ can not be controlled by $\|u\|_{2,p}$ using such inequalities.

Comment: What I was thinking was to use an interpolation like $\| |\nabla u|^2\|_p \leq C \|u\|_\infty\|u\|_{2,p}$ (this is an exercise in Evans by the way). On a bounded domain the maximum principle can be used to bound $\|u\|_\infty \leq \lambda^{-1} \|f\|_\infty$. Maybe you can approximate the solution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a sequence of solutions on bounded domains.

Comment: Then for $\kappa$ small enough (or $\lambda$ large enough), you can absorb into left hand side. Sorry, the idea with Young's inequality does not work as you said.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is the Cole-Hopf transformation to get rid of the nonlinear term: Set $v = e^{-ku}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help and patient answer.